# Why is c_str not working in this open(filename) case

Tags: c++, string, file-io, std, c-str

I thought I understood having to cast a std::string as a *char when opening a file, but I am missing something.  It compiles fine but does not open.  Tried a number of variations but so far only hardcoding the name in the file is working:

```
//  const char * cEMN = cCCA.get_EMNfn().c_str();
//  femn.open(cEMN);  fails
//  femn.open("file-foo.emn"); works

string stdEMN;
stdEMN = cCCA.get_EMNfn();
femn.open(stdEMN.c_str());  // fails

if(!femn)
{
    cout << "Open of Original EMN file failed\n";
    cout << "EMN file: " << cCCA.get_EMNfn() << endl;
    cout << "Press any key to exit" << endl;
    ch = getchar();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Try to display `cCCA.get_EMNfn().c_str()`. Does it give exactly `file-foo.emn`?

Answer (score 3):

The facts as I discern them to be are that:

```
femn.open("file-foo.emn");
```

succeeds. But

```
femn.open(stdEMN.c_str());
```

fails.

The obvious conclusion is that `stdEMN.c_str()` evaluates to a string that differs from `"file-foo.emn"`.

Comment: Not the case as you can see my error code sends the filename to the screen in the case of a failure and unless I'm going blind they appear to be the same thing

Comment: If stdEMN.c_str() does evaluates equal to "file-foo.emn", then the call to `open` will succeed. Surely. Unless the computer hates you. Not likely.

Comment: I'd look at the bytes and make sure there isn't extra unprintable stuff in there (Or different encodings?) because this is almost certainly what's happening.